# django input element error css class

Tags: python, django, validation, django-forms

I'd like to know how can I add .error class to input elements ([to registration app](http://django-registration.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/registration/)) when the form validation fails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done completely through your template.

You build the form template for each form field that you want to test you can use the following example construct

```
<input type="text" class="reg-txt{% if form.fieldname.errors %} errors{% endif %}"/>
```

This lets you provide the interface you want without modifying the view & django form code.

Comment: Is there anything that can be done on the form or widget level? This seems rather verbose, I would want to have this error class on every invalid input field, textarea, select...

Answer (score 33):

If you want to place your error CSS class to form input widgets (not their containers), you can derive your form class from the following one:

```
class StyledErrorForm(forms.Form):
     def is_valid(self):
         result = super().is_valid()
         # loop on *all* fields if key '__all__' found else only on errors:
         for x in (self.fields if '__all__' in self.errors else self.errors):
             attrs = self.fields[x].widget.attrs
             attrs.update({'class': attrs.get('class', '') + ' is-invalid'})
         return result
```

Comment: Watch out for a small gotcha, though, — this overrides any class that was specified in field widget declaration (i.e. `attrs`). To simply append error class, use this line instead (slightly horrible): `self.fields[f].widget.attrs.update({'class': self.fields[f].widget.attrs.get('class', '') + ' error'})`

Comment: Your answer is not complete, you've forgotten the `__all__` key. I've edited your answer, to correct it, if you dont like it tell me.

Answer (score 26):

It's now easy -- new feature in Django 1.2

Just add an attribute on the form class & you're good to go. This feature is mentioned in the docs under a "new in 1.2" note, but you can find the magic at `django.forms.forms.BoundField.css_classes` Here's the [API reference](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#customizing-the-error-list-format), and an example:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    required_css_class = "required"
    error_css_class = "error"
```

Comment: I'm running 1.3 and neither of those classes are ever in the template output. I'm rendering the field with the simple {{ field }} in a for loop. Anything special I have to do to make that work? Does it only work when outputing tables?

Comment: You need to output the entire form using {{ form }}, if you do it that way you will see the classes in any of the formats (p, table and list).

Comment: @BrianFisher based on your answer does that mean either accept {{form}} as to get desired error/required class or build your own elements if you want finer control over entire form and the classes on error?

Comment: Yes, adding `required_css_class` or `error_css_class` only affects the container elements around an input's label and field when output using `{{ form }}`. It does *not* add the classes to the input field itself (which is what the OP wanted). [Here are the docs for Django 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/api/#styling-required-or-erroneous-form-rows)

Comment: Django 3.x: if you override `clean()` method, and in that method, add error through `self.add_error()` (of raise a `ValidationError()` Exception), `error_css_class` is *ignored*. Dont ask me why. In this case, this answer doesn't work, whereas Luca's answer works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Custom Template...

Personally never had much luck using the built in Django error classing solutions, and besides, I like to use the built in 'striptags' template filter on the errors, to get rid of all the html list stuff which I cant figure out how to render nicely anyway.

I use the following custom template to class them as 'error_id'.

```
@register.filter(is_safe=True)
@stringfilter
def error_id(value):
    if value=='':
        return ''
    else:
        return r'<span class="error_id">'+value+'</span>'
```

Render the individual errors in your template using:

```
{{ form.my_field.errors|striptags|error_id}}
```

Or render the whole form using something like:

```
    <table border="1" cellpadding="5px" align="center">
        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            <tr>
                        <td> {{ field.label_tag }}: </td>
                        <td>    {{ field }}  </td>
                        <td> {{ field.errors|striptags|error_id }} </td>
            </tr>

        {% endfor %}

    </table>
```

Comment: I use `{{ field.errors.join:" " }}` to display errors inline instead of `ul`. And no HTML stuff.

Comment: You can call striptags from within your filter from django.template.defaultfilters.stiptags

Answer (score 0):

(Better late than never)

You should be able to do this with [Django Uni Form](http://github.com/pydanny/django-uni-form)